# How to delete the last item of a listview and refresh the view correctly?

Tags: android, listview, refresh

"Gelöscht" means "Deleted" in English...
"Löschen" means "delete" in English...

Everything works in homework.java but not in the second part (mark.java). So why isn't it work in mark.java but here? It's like the same code...

I have a ListView with homework in it like you can see: (homework.java)

[image: Pic 1]

When I delete the last item it refreshes correctly:

[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 3]

What happens if "Löschen" has been touched... (CONTEXT_MENU_DELTE_ITEM)

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //Adapterview definieren
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);                            //Gibt die ID des gedrückten Items zurück

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM:                                              //Wenn die Auswahl auf CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM fiel
                String id_delete = Long.toString(id);                                   //Die Item ID wird dem String zugewiesen
                try {
                    delItem(id_delete);                                                 //Löschen des Items (siehe Funktionen) mit der ID id_delete
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Gelöscht!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       //Anzeige "Gelöscht!"
                    fillData();                                                         //ListView wieder mit DB Daten füllen
                    registerForContextMenu(getListView());                              //ContextMenu registrieren
                }
                catch(SQLiteException e){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Nicht gelöscht!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Bei einem Fehler: Nicht gelöscht...
                }
                return(true);

                case CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT_ITEM:                                            //Wenn die Auswahl auf CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT_ITEM fiel
                    try {
                    id_edit = Long.toString(id);                                        //Die Item ID wird dem String zugewiesen
                    mDbHelper.open_database_rw();                                       //Datenbank wird geöffnet

                    Cursor cursor = db.query("tbl_homework", new String[] {"hw"},       //Dem Cursor wird der Eintrag "hw" in der Tabelle tbl_homework zugewiesen, welcher die _id vom Item hat
                                    "_id="+id_edit, null, null, null, null);
                    startManagingCursor(cursor);                                        //Managed den Cursor                

                    cursor.moveToFirst();                                               //Cursor an den Anfang setzen
                    int column = cursor.getColumnIndex("hw");                           //Der SpaltenIndex in column schreiben
                    hw = cursor.getString(column);                                      //String in hw schreiben (wird bei den Dialogen wieder benötigt!)
                    showDialog(EDIT_HW_DIALOG);                                         //EDIT_HW_DIALOG Dialog aufrufen, siehe Dialoge

                    fillData();                                                         //ListView mit DB Einträgen füllen

                    }
                    catch(SQLiteException e){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Nicht gelöscht!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Meldung: Nicht gelöscht, bei Fehler
                    }
                    return(true);
        }
      return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));                                        //Selektierte Item wird zurückgegeben
    }
```

Funkctions....

```
    /** AlertDialog: Fehler-Nachrichten-Funktion */
    private void fillData() {
        c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();                                                          //Cursor c mit fetchAllNotes von dbHelper.java initialisieren
        startManagingCursor(c);                                                                         //Managed den Cursor
        String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.HOMEWORK_ROW_HW, dbHelper.HOMEWORK_ROW_HWDATE};         //Datenzuweisung dem String from
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txt_notes_row, R.id.txt_homework};                                   //Datenzuweisung dem Integer to

        //ArrayAdapter deklarieren und anzeigen
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_homework, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    /** delItem: Funktion zum Löschen von einem Datensatz */
    public void delItem(String item){
        db.delete("tbl_homework", "_id="+item, null);           //Datensatz löschen
    }
```

But in my second ListView I have some marks in it. When I try to delete the last one there
it has been deleted in database (I checked that) but didn't refresh the ListView like in homework. I always has to restart my activity first. But in homework I don't have to... 
My question is why and how can I fix it? (marks.java)

[image: Pic 4]
[image: Pic 5]
[image: Pic 6]

What happens if "Löschen" has been touched... (CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM)

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
     long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position); /*what item was selected is ListView*/

     switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM:
                 mDbHelper.open_database_rw();
                 String id_delete = Long.toString(id);
                 try{
                     delItem(id_delete);
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Note gelöscht!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     fillData();
                     registerForContextMenu(getListView());
                 }
                 catch(SQLiteException e){
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Nicht gelöscht!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                 return(true);

             case CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT_ITEM:
                 try{
                     mDbHelper.open_database_rw();
                     id_edit = Long.toString(id);

                     cursor = db.query("tbl_marks", new String[] {"name", "mark", "gewicht"}, 
                        "_id="+id_edit, null, null, null, null);
                     startManagingCursor(cursor);

                     cursor.moveToFirst();

                     int name_mark = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
                     name = cursor.getString(name_mark);
                     int mark_mark = cursor.getColumnIndex("mark");
                     mark = cursor.getString(mark_mark);
                     int mark_gewicht_int = cursor.getColumnIndex("gewicht");
                     gewicht_mark = cursor.getString(mark_gewicht_int);
                     gewicht_mark_int = Integer.parseInt(gewicht_mark);
                     removeDialog(EDIT_MARK_DIALOG);
                     showDialog(EDIT_MARK_DIALOG);
                     registerForContextMenu(getListView());
                     fillData();
                     cursor.close();
                 }
                 catch(SQLiteException e){
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Nicht gelöscht!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                 return(true);
     }
 return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
 }
```

Functions...

```
private void fillData() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String txt_sub_id = extras.getString("IDFach");
    int test = Integer.parseInt(txt_sub_id);

    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, subid, name, mark, gewicht, datum FROM tbl_marks WHERE subid = '"+test+"';", null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         zahl1 = 0;
         zahl2 = 0;
         int intMark = cursor.getColumnIndex("mark");
         int intWeight = cursor.getColumnIndex("gewicht");
          do {
              float weight = cursor.getFloat(intWeight);
              float mark = cursor.getFloat(intMark);

              zahl1 = zahl1 + (weight * mark);
              zahl2 = zahl2 + weight;
          } while (cursor.moveToNext());

          cursor.moveToFirst(); //bringing cursor to first place

          String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.MARKS_ROW_NAME, dbHelper.MARKS_ROW_MARK, dbHelper.MARKS_ROW_GEWICHT, dbHelper.MARKS_ROW_DATUM};
              int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txt_marks_row, R.id.txt_note, R.id.txt_gewicht, R.id.txt_datum};


          txt_durchschnitt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_durchschnitt);
          result = zahl1 / zahl2;

          float result_neu = (float) (Math.round(result * 100) / 100.0);

          txt_durchschnitt.setText(""+result_neu);
          SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_marks, cursor, from, to);
          setListAdapter(notes);
    }
}

public void delItem(String item){
    db.delete("tbl_marks", "_id="+item, null);
}
```

Comment: Where you delete an item from listview,you should re-populate listview by settting its adapter again after delete statement of listitem.That is a good way of achieving what you are trying to.

Comment: did U tried with listView.invalidate()?

Comment: @PadmaKumar yes I did... It didn't work. I am wondering about that why it's working at homework.java and in mark.java not... Thanks!

Comment: @Hiral How do you mean that? My English is to bad to understand that. Thanks

Comment: @MarcoSeiz: oh sorry,you already did that.I missed to notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple why you are getting this problem:

for homework:

function is:

```
private void fillData() {

        c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();                                                          //Cursor c mit fetchAllNotes von dbHelper.java initialisieren
        startManagingCursor(c);                                                                         //Managed den Cursor
        String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.HOMEWORK_ROW_HW, dbHelper.HOMEWORK_ROW_HWDATE};         //Datenzuweisung dem String from
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txt_notes_row, R.id.txt_homework};                                   //Datenzuweisung dem Integer to

        //ArrayAdapter deklarieren und anzeigen
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_homework, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
```

Where for marks:

function is:

```
private void fillData() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String txt_sub_id = extras.getString("IDFach");
    int test = Integer.parseInt(txt_sub_id);

    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, subid, name, mark, gewicht, datum FROM tbl_marks WHERE subid = '"+test+"';", null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

          //your code

          SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_marks, cursor, from, to);
          setListAdapter(notes);
    }
}
```

See the difference in both.

In 1st one,you run the code for whatever you get into cursor(empty cursor or filled cursor) and set the adapter.

Where in 2nd one,you check for the condition that if cursor is not null,then only you reset the adapter to listview.So when you delete last item from table,there is no record into it resulting cursor empty and hence your new adapter(with empty cursor) will never set to your listview.

To overcome,add this line to your marks's fillData() method like:

```
private void fillData() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String txt_sub_id = extras.getString("IDFach");
    int test = Integer.parseInt(txt_sub_id);

    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, subid, name, mark, gewicht, datum FROM tbl_marks WHERE subid = '"+test+"';", null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

          //your code

          SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_marks, cursor, from, to);
          setListAdapter(notes);
    }
    else
    {
       String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.MARKS_ROW_NAME, dbHelper.MARKS_ROW_MARK, dbHelper.MARKS_ROW_GEWICHT, dbHelper.MARKS_ROW_DATUM};
       int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txt_marks_row, R.id.txt_note, R.id.txt_gewicht, R.id.txt_datum};
       SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_marks, cursor, from, to);
       setListAdapter(notes); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you thousand times :D That solved my problem. I didn't take care about my if clause. Thanks!